# Why are independent random variables always uncorrelated?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to show that, if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables, then $\mathbb E(XY)=\mathbb E(X)\mathbb E(Y)$.

For the purposes of this question, assume that $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative.  This assumption is not necessary, but it's the case I'd like to consider first.

In that case, we can write $\mathbb E(XY)$ as

$$
\int_0^\infty \mathbb P(XY\ge\lambda)d\lambda
$$

But I don't know how to convert that into the equivalent expression for the expectation product.  Note that I don't want to assume that either X or Y has a density function.

Comment: That integral looks real fishy.

Comment: You should probably check out Wikipedia's page on expectation, specifically [the part that discusses this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Non-multiplicativity).

Comment: @dfeuer The Wikipedia article was the first place I looked.  If you read my question, you'll see that I said that I don't want to assume that either $X$ or $Y$ has a distribution, while the link you gave only discusses the case when they have a joint distribution.  Also, the integral is correct; if you disagree, then maybe you should check out the Wikipedia article on expected value, specifically the section on "formulas for special cases".

Comment: Do you know measure theory?  The result can be proved in complete generality there, as an (immediate) consequence of Fubini's Theorem.  This is because the joint measure of two independent random variables is precisely the product measure obtained from their (marginal) measures.

Comment: My instinct is to write $\Bbb P(XY\ge\lambda)$ as $\int_0^\infty \Bbb P(X=\alpha) \Bbb P(Y \ge \lambda/\alpha) \,d\alpha$ and start switching integrals.

Comment: Aren't you already assuming that density functions exist? Otherwise, how do you define $\mathbb{E}(X)$? Also, I don't see why you would not want to make this assumtion.

Comment: @dreamer I define $\mathbb E(X)$ to be the integral of the random variable $X$ with respect to the probability measure.  I don't want to assume that the random  variables have densities because some random variables haven't got densities.

Comment: @GregMartin In general, for continuous random variables (taking values in the reals with Lebesgue measure), $\mathbb P(X=\alpha)=0$.

Comment: @Donkey_2009: I know, I meant infinitesimally ... maybe it's better to add $d\lambda$ to both sides of my instinct.